# How can I change a Cell image when a user selects it?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my custom cell subclass, when user selects a cell I want to change an image on it, which is a property by retain. No nib, everything is with code.

Problems:

-First, Even nothing is selected still the cell appears with the new image on it.

-Second, when I click nothing changes on the cell;

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
UIImage *cry = [UIImage APP_CRYSTAL_SELECTED];
self.leftImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cry] autorelease] ;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.leftImage];
 }
```

Comment: Are you talking about a tableviewcell or a button?

Comment: Not sure but you can try 'setHighlighted:animated:'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not check to see if it is selected or not in your code example.

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if(selected)
    {
        UIImage *cry = [UIImage APP_CRYSTAL_SELECTED];
        self.leftImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cry] autorelease] ;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.leftImage];
    }
    else
    {
        //Remove image here if it exists
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx my all image logic should be in setselected? for instance I set my default image in initWithCellIdentifier, should I move it to set selected? and remove the view before I set a new one in if else?

Comment: You can set the default image in initWithCellIdentifier and also set it back to the default in the else statement from above.

Comment: then I also have to remove the image from contentView in the if statement?

Comment: Since you are adding to self.contentView yes remove the image in the else statement. If you check to see if it has already been added then all you would need to do is set the image on self.leftImage.

Comment: confused, if I am only changing the image which added into contentView, then I should only change where that points to, so no removing adding anymore?